# Curve fitting in Python, need almost exact match of the shape of the curve rather than a curve that minimize mean square difference

Tags: python, curve-fitting

The curve and my attempt at fitting:

[image: Curve and my attempt at fitting]

I wish to find the coefficients `(A, B, C, D, E, F)` for my model function: `A * x**2 + B * x + C * np.cos(D * x - E) + F` that would almost exactly match the blue curve. But because I used SciPy's optimization `curve_fit`, which finds the curve with the lowest square difference, it's going to look like the red curve in the image. While I would want the red curve to match up with the crests and troughs of the blue curve. Can `scipy` do this and how do you do it. If not is there any other library that can handle this?

Comment: Choose proper starting values, especially for `D`

Comment: @Simon. I agree with mikuszefski's comment. That is the difficulty. In order to overcome this difficulty use another method of regression which doesn't requires initial values  nor iterative calculus. If you joint numerical data to your question instead of a graph I would show how to proceed. (Method adapted from https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales ).

Comment: @JJacquelin  just applied that method. ready to post (on generic data) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the method mentioned by JJacquelin to make a double linear fit. It fits the data and can be used to provide initial guesses for the non-linear fit. Note that for this method, it is required to express `P sin( w t + p )` as `A sin( w t ) + B cos( w t )`, but that is easily done.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def signal( x, A, B, C, D, E, F ):
    ### note: C, D, E, F have different meaning here
    r = (
        A * x**2 
        + B * x
        + C
        + D * np.sin( F * x )
        + E * np.cos( F * x )
    )
    return r

def signal_p( x, A, B, C, D, E, F ):
    r = (
        A * x**2 
        + B * x
        + C * np.sin( D * x - E )
        + F
    )
    return r

testparams = [ -1, 1, 3, 0.005, 0.03, 22 ]

### test data with noise
xl = np.linspace( -0.3, 1.6, 190 )
sl = signal( xl, *testparams )
sl += np.random.normal( size=len( xl ), scale=0.005 )

### numerical integrals
Sl = cumtrapz( sl, x=xl, initial=0 )
SSl = cumtrapz( Sl, x=xl, initial=0 )

### fitting the integro-differential equation to get the frequency
"""
note: 
    with y = A x**2 +...+ D sin() + E cos()
    the double integral int( int(y) ) = a x**4 + ... - y/F**2
"""
VMXT = np.array( [ xl**4, xl**3, xl**2, xl, np.ones( len( xl ) ), sl ] )
VMX = VMXT.transpose()

A = np.dot( VMXT, VMX )
SV = np.dot( VMXT, SSl )
AI = np.linalg.inv( A )
result = np.dot( AI , SV )
print ( "Fit: ",result )
F = np.sqrt( -1 / result[-1] )
print("F = ", F)

### Fitting the linear parameters with the frequency known
VMXT = np.array( 
    [
        xl**2, xl, np.ones( len( xl ) ),
        np.sin( F * xl), np.cos( F * xl )
    ]
)
VMX = VMXT.transpose()

A = np.dot( VMXT, VMX )
SV = np.dot( VMXT, sl )
AI = np.linalg.inv( A )
A, B, C, D, E = np.dot( AI , SV )
print( A, B, C, D, E )

### Non-linear fit with initial guesses
amp = np.sqrt( D**2 + E**2 )
phi = -np.arctan( D / E )
opt, cov = curve_fit( signal_p, xl, sl, p0=( A, B, amp, F, phi, C ) )
print( opt )

### plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )

ax.plot(
    xl, sl,
    ls='', marker='+', label="data", markersize=5
)
ax.plot(
    xl, signal( xl, A, B, C, D, E, F ),
    ls="--", label="double linear fit"
)
ax.plot(
    xl, signal_p( xl, *opt ),
    ls=":", label="non-linear"
)
ax.legend( loc=0 )
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

Providing

```py
Fit:  [-0.083161  0.1659759 1.49879056 0.848999 0.130222 -0.001990]
F =  22.414133356157887
 -0.998516    0.998429    3.000265    0.012701    0.026926
[-0.99856269  0.9973273   0.0305014  21.96402992 -1.4215656   3.00100979]
```

and
[image: fit]

When using the non-linear fit without initial guesses, I get basically a parabola. One can understand why when visualizing a sine half-wave. That is basically a parabola as well. Hence, the non-linear fit drives the according parameters in that direction, especially knowing that the default initial guesses are `1`. So one is far off the small amplitude and the high frequency. The fit only finds a local minimum in the chi-square hyper-plane.

Comment: Massive thanks. It works very well, but the method is still quite unclear to me. It is unfortunate I can't open the website JJacquelin sent in the comment. Could you tell me the name of the method and I will see if I can search it up on some other websites. I suppose it is commonly used in signal processing?

Comment: @Simon well, I'm not sure what the official name is. The title of the work is "Regression and integral equations". It is in french, but not hard to read. The main idea is to rephrase your question in terms of an integro-differential equation such that a non-linear parameter of the function pops up linear in the differential equation. Most simple example is `y = a sin( k x )` where `y'' = k**2 y` but you may make it far more complicated, like e.g. `l` of the Legendre differential equation. Note: it works for dense data, and error estimates and error-propagation seem to be problematic (at best)